# Does language linkage only belong to a function?

Tags: c++, linkage

In [Lischner's C++ in a Nutshell 2002](https://books.google.com/books?id=Q4iP1mkfdtsC&lpg=PT39&ots=w_m99yO-7q&dq=Every%20function%2C%20function%20type%2C%20and%20object%20has%20a%20language%20linkage%2C%20which%20is%20specified%20as%20a%20simple%20character%20string.%20By%20default%2C%20the%20linkage%20is&pg=PT39#v=onepage&q=Every%20function,%20function%20type,%20and%20object%20has%20a%20language%20linkage,%20which%20is%20specified%20as%20a%20simple%20character%20string.%20By%20default,%20the%20linkage%20is&f=false)

> **Every function, function type, and object has a language linkage,** which is specified as a simple character string. By default, the
>   linkage is "C++". The only other standard language linkage is "C". All
>   other language linkages and the properties associated with different
>   language linkages are implementation-defined.

Does language linkage only belong to a function, not a non-function object? The examples that I have seen seem to say yes. But I guess I miss something.

What does the quote mean by each 'function type' and 'object' having a language linkage?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking if the quote from the book is wrong?

Comment: I'm too lazy to go standards-diving to produce the proper answer, but supposing the book is correct and can be supported from the standard, I'm pretty sure the reason you won't see examples of language linkage for objects, is that implementations don't actually need to use different name-mangling or other linker details for C and C++ linkage, so in practice language linkage makes no difference for objects.

Answer (score 0):

No, variables can have language linkage too.

First of all, your book paraphrases standard:

> All function types, function names with external linkage, **and variable names** with external linkage have a language linkage.

This alone suggests that you can apply linkage specifications to variables.

Further down there is this example:

```
extern "C" int i; // declaration
extern "C" {
    int i; // definition
}
```

Which shows how can you apply linkage specifier to non-function. In addition there are multiple mentions of *functions* and *variables* through whole **[dcl.link]** chapter of standard.

Answer (score 0):

Language linkage specifications are intended to enable linking into the same program object files originating from different source languages.

The problem is that, in general, names of entities (functions, variables, etc) in object files do not exactly match the names of the corresponding entities in the source code.

C, being  an old and "simple" language, didn't concern itself with such considerations and used source names in the object files as is.

C++, building on top of C, introduced function overloading, allowing different functions to have the same name. Therefore the signature of C++ functions had to be encoded in the symbol name representing that function in an object file.

Besides, names of C++ entities may contain the following characters (that could not appear in C identifiers):

1. **`:`** - in fully qualified names (`std::cout`)
2. **`<`**, **`>`** - in the names of template specializations
3. **`+`**, **`-`**, **`*`**, **`/`** and other special symbols - in the names of overloaded operators

Probably enough, old linkers would have trouble dealing with such characters in symbols names, therefore the C++ compilers had to encode those characters using the safe subset.

Non-function entities in C++ (namely - namespace variables, static data members of non-template and template classes) can have the characters **`:`**, **`<`**, and **`>`** in their names . Therefore, if we consider only C and C++, variables must have language linkage too. However, if a C++ variable's fully qualified name (without including the leading global namespace prefix) doesn't contain the mentioned characters, then its symbol name coincides with its source name. As a result I cannot think of a case when specifying "C" linkage for a variable makes a difference.

In principle, the language linkage specification allows importing names from modules compiled from other programming languages (though, as noted in your quote, those are implementation-defined). If you ever need to link with such a foreign language module and refer to a "global" variable therein, you will first have to declare it in your source file using the language linkage specification:

```
extern "Sci++" {
    MemAllocFuncPtr Solver##Config##Malloc;

    // Won't the '#' chararcters in the identifier name confuse the C++ compiler?
    // Maybe C++ will need to be enhanced as below:
    using SciPPSolverConfigMalloc = Solver##Config##Malloc;
}
```

Yet, I don't believe that you will encounter anything like that in practice.